# LOTUS (law of the unconscious statistician) for non-one-to-one functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory, functions, random-variables, expected-value

My textbook, *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang, defines LOTUS (law of the unconscious statistician) as follows:

> **Theorem 4.5.1** (LOTUS). If $X$ is a discrete r.v. and $g$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then
>
> $$E(g(X)) = \sum_x g(x) P(X = x),$$
>
> where the sum is taken over all possible values of $X$.
>
> This means that we can get the expected value of $g(X)$ knowing only $P(X = x)$, the PMF of $X$; we don't need to know the PMF of $g(X)$. The name comes from the fact that in going from $E(X)$ to $E(g(X))$ it is tempting to just change $x$ to $g(x)$ in the definition, which can be done very easily and mechanically, perhaps in a state of unconsciousness. On second thought, it may sound too good to be true that finding the distribution of $g(X)$ is not needed for this calculation, but LOTUS says it *is* true.
>
> Before proving LOTUS in general, let's see why it is true in some special cases. Let $X$ have support $0, 1, 2, \dots$ with probabilities $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots$, so the PMF is $P(X = n) = p_n$. Then $X^3$ has support $0^3, 1^3, 2^3, \dots$ with probabilities $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots$, so
>
> $$\begin{align} &E(X) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n p_n, \\ &E(X^3) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n^3 p_n \end{align}$$
>
> As claimed by LOTUS, to edit the expression for $E(X)$ into an expression for $E(X^3)$, we can just change the $n$ in front of the $p_n$ to an $n^3$; the $p_n$ is unchanged, and we can still use the PMF of $X$. This was an easy example since the function $g(x) = x^3$ is one-to-one. But LOTUS holds much more generally.

This begs the question, which does not seem to be answered by the author: What happens in the case where the function $g(x)$ is *not* one-to-one? How does one deal with this case? How does our application of LOTUS change?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this.

Comment: Why do you think $g$ not being one-to-one might cause a problem?

Comment: I mean, it’s clear that you know it shouldn’t, since LOTUS is a known result, but I think you’ll get better answers to your question if you articulate what concerns you about the case when $g$ is not injective.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Based on the language of the author, they seem to be implicitly implying that $g(x)$ not being one-to-one *does* cause problems: "*This was an easy example since the function $g(x) = x^3$ is one-to-one*."

Comment: If $g$ is one-to-one, it's easy to find the distribution of $g(X)$. So in this case it's easier to understand why LOTUS is true.

Comment: @littleO indeed, but how does one deal with the case where $g(x)$ *isn't* one-to-one? How does our application of LOTUS change?

Comment: The application of LOTUS doesn't change at all, it just becomes more difficult to understand why LOTUS is true.

Comment: @littleO Oh, I see. So it is still perfectly valid to use LOTUS for functions that aren't one-to-one?

Comment: Yes, perfectly valid.

Comment: @littleO Ahh, ok, that clarifies things for me then. Thank you for the assistance.